# Can a mamzer, Ammonite, or Moabite enter the temple after ten generations?

Tags: marriage, ki-teitzei

Does [Deuteronomy 23:3-4](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.23.3-4?lang=bi&aliyot=0) mean these people can never enter the temple or must count 10 generations forward before they can enter the temple.  The scripture is a bit ambiguous.

> לֹא־יָבֹ֥א מַמְזֵ֖ר בִּקְהַ֣ל יְהוָ֑ה גַּ֚ם דּ֣וֹר עֲשִׂירִ֔י
>   לֹא־יָ֥בֹא ל֖וֹ בִּקְהַ֥ל יְהוָֽה׃
>
> No one misbegotten shall be admitted into the congregation of the
>   LORD; none of his descendants, even in the tenth generation, shall be
>   admitted into the congregation of the LORD.
>
> לֹֽא־יָבֹ֧א עַמּוֹנִ֛י וּמוֹאָבִ֖י בִּקְהַ֣ל יְהוָ֑ה גַּ֚ם דּ֣וֹר
>   עֲשִׂירִ֔י לֹא־יָבֹ֥א לָהֶ֛ם בִּקְהַ֥ל יְהוָ֖ה עַד־עוֹלָֽם׃
>
> No Ammonite or Moabite shall be admitted into the congregation of the
>   LORD; none of their descendants, even in the tenth generation, shall
>   ever be admitted into the congregation of the LORD

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

These people (i.e., a child born from adultery, an Amonite or a Moavite) may not marry a Jewish woman of unflawed lineage, forever.

A child born from adultery (a *mamzer*) remains a Jew and can marry women of similarly flawed lineage (i.e., a *mamzeret*).

Source: the [Steinsaltz Humash](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9653019120)

Comment: And converts from other nations can marry either these people or Jews of unflawed lineage.